# How can I create a separate month and year picker in swiftUI?

Tags: date, swiftui

I'm working on a month and year picker, I want them to be separate, and the order of the months is always the same (January, February etc.) I've already managed to create this view, but when I select November, for example, it doesn't change to November.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance.

This is my MonthPicker code:

```
struct MonthPicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CalendarViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $viewModel.selectedDate) {
            ForEach(generateMonths(), id: \.self) { monthString in
                Text(monthString)
                    .tag(monthString)
            }
        }
        .labelsHidden()
        // Entfernen Sie den datePickerStyle-Modifikator
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .onChange(of: viewModel.selectedDate, perform: { newDate in
            // Handle month change here
        })
    }

    private func generateMonths() -> [String] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentDate = Date()
        var months: [String] = []

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"

        for i in 0..<12 {
            if let date = calendar.date(bySetting: .month, value: i + 1, of: currentDate) {
                let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                months.append(monthString)
            }
        }

        return months
    }
}
```

This is my generateMonths code:

```
 private func generateMonths() -> [String] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentDate = Date()
        let startOfYear = calendar.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
        var months: [String] = []

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"

        for i in 0..<12 {
            if let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: i, to: startOfYear) {
                let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                months.append(monthString)
            }
        }

        return months
    }
```

And this is how I display the month at the end:

```
struct test: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = CalendarViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack (){
            Spacer()
            MonthPicker(viewModel: viewModel)
                .padding()
                .labelsHidden()
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is my CalenderViewModel:

```
class CalendarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date()
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], something that I can directly copy and paste into Xcode to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: I hope that's enough for you.

Comment: So you have a `selectedDate` of type `Date`, and this doesn't make sense. What do you expect `selectedDate` to be when you select "January"? Keep in mind that a `Date` represents a point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I suggest you create a dedicated structure to represent a month and use it as the value for the Picker.

- Create a structure for the month: This structure will contain the month name and month number.
- Modify generateMonths to return a list of these structures.
- Update the Picker to use this structure as a tag.
- Ensure that viewModel.selectedDate is correctly updated when the user chooses a month.

--

```
struct MonthItem: Identifiable {

    let id: Int 
    let name: String

    init(month: Int, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) {
        self.id = month
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
        if let date = calendar.date(bySetting: .month, value: month, of: Date()) {
            self.name = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            self.name = ""
        }
    }
}



private func generateMonths() -> [MonthItem] {

    return (1...12).map { MonthItem(month: $0) }

}

Picker("", selection: $viewModel.selectedMonth) {
    ForEach(generateMonths()) { month in
        Text(month.name).tag(month.id)
    }
}
.onChange(of: viewModel.selectedMonth) { newMonth in
    // Update selectedDate with new selected month
}


 class CalendarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedMonth: Int // Here, store the number of the selected month
    @Published var selectedDate: Date // Use this date to reflect the selected month and year
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Picker` items all have strings as their tags, but your selection value `selectedDate` is a `Date`.

This doesn't make sense, because it doesn't make sense to get a `Date` (representing an *instant* in time) from just a month selector.

I would keep this simple - have the month and year picker both take simple `Int`s as `@Binding`s.

```
struct MonthPicker: View {
    @Binding var month: Int
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $month) {
            // generateMonths is redundant. You can get the month names using Calendar.monthSymbols
            let months = calendar.monthSymbols
            ForEach(months.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                // note the values of the tags
                Text(months[i])
                    .tag(i + 1)
            }
        }
        .labelsHidden()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

struct YearPicker: View {
    @Binding var year: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        // not sure how you want the year picker to look, so I'll just use a text field as an example
        TextField("Year", value: $year, format: .number.grouping(.never))
    }
}
```

In your view model, use two `Int` properties, or a `DateComponents`, to store the selected values. Either way, you are able to pass two `Binding`s to the pickers. `$viewModel.month`/`$viewModel.year`, or `$viewModel.dateComponents.month`/`$viewModel.dateComponents.year`.

Here is the two pickers combined in an `HStack`. I'll use a `@State` of type `DateComponents` here to keep things simple.

```
@State var dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 12)

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        // the if statements are here because dateComponents.month/year is optional
        // consider force unwrapping if you are sure they won't be null
        // i.e. Binding($dateComponents.month)
        if let monthBinding = Binding($dateComponents.month) {
            MonthPicker(month: monthBinding)
        }
        if let yearBinding = Binding($dateComponents.year) {
            YearPicker(year: yearBinding)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get a `Date` out of this, you can do:

```
@Environment(\.calendar) var calendar

var date: Date? {
    calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
}
```

This creates a `Date` representing the first day of the selected month in the selected year, at midnight in the local timezone.